# How to make a video from a still image and an audio file?

Tags: video, audio, osx

I have an image file (png) and an audio file (aiff).  How do I combine them to make a video file that shows the still image and plays the audio file?

Target operating system: either OS X Lion or Ubuntu, using only free software, must be command-line driven (no GUI solutions please).  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm curious why you accepted my answer rather than Josh's more detailed answer that includes a how-to article. I don't mind the reputation points, but it seems like the other answer better addresses your question.

Comment: I do actually need the audio added to the video, so although I like the article, it doesn't solve my problem.  Even though your answer doesn't actually offer a ready-made solution, I prefer to accept one so as to boost my accept rating (making it more likely that others will continue to answer my questions).  Sadly this is a feature of StackExchange---it incentivizes askers to accept an answer, even if it doesn't completely answer the question.

Comment: I completely agree that you should make a point of accepting good answers, but when you do so is a matter of personal preference. I don't ask a lot of questions, so often like to give a weak answer 5-7 days before I accept it. AVP's traffic is light, and people don't seem shy about adding late answers, so it may not be a big deal.

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/1041816/combine-one-image-one-audio-file-to-make-one-video-using-ffmpeg

Answer (score 11):

To expand upon ObscureRobot's answer, use ffmpeg like so:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -f image2 -r 2 -i input1.png -i input2.aiff -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -shortest output.mp4
```

`-loop 1 -f image2 -r 2 -i input1.png` tells ffmpeg to loop input1.png forever, at a frame rate of 2fps. `-c:v libx264` tells it to [use x264 to encode the video](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide), and `-c:a copy` tells it to simply copy the audio, without encoding. `-shortest` makes ffmpeg stop when the shortest input ends - input2.aiff in this case.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://www.itforeveryone.co.uk/image-to-video.html) looks like it'll get you close.  Doesn't include the audio, but that honestly sounds easier than converting the images to video.

Excerpt:

> ImageMagick and ffmpeg combined can be used to turn still images into
>   video. Both ImageMagick and ffmpeg have been around for years, and are
>   readily available as packages with most Linux distributions. The tips
>   below allow you to convert images on the command line, which for a may
>   appear to be time consuming, but once you know how to do it you'll
>   find it much faster than using a GUI!